# What does this mean about a person's personality ?どこかずれてるというか。危なっかしいというか (2 people are talking about their little sisters)

Tags: meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension

My guess is that their little sisters are a little bit weird in their way of thinking? But I don't understand these 2 expressions "どこかずれてる" and "危なっかしい". I would appreciate if someone can explain to me the correct meaning of this sentence and these 2 expressions:

**"どこかずれてるというか。危なっかしいというか"**

Full conversation:

A「そうだ、この前妹がいるって言ってたけど俺にもいるんだ」

B「そうなんですか。どういう方ですか」

A「うーん。君の妹と同じで勉強はできるな」

B「ご立派ですね」【少女】

**A「でも、頭はいいはずなのに……どこかずれてるというか。危なっかしいというか」**

B「あ、うちの妹もそうです。頭はいいのにどこかずれてるんですよね」

A「へぇ」

B「服のセンスとかも、黒が好きで……それだけならいいんですが、魔女みたいな服ばっかり選ぶんです」

Answer (score 2):

Both are used for describing the sister's characteristics.

ずれている derives from [ずれる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%9A%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B/#je-39723), which literally means *off from the correct position, off the standard*. When used as in the question, it generally means the same thing and used to describe someone who is a bit odd or not ordinary. どこか adds the sense that the oddity is hard to describe.

あぶなかっしい is literally *look dangerous*. A more ordinary usage is

- 5歳児が包丁を使うのは危なっかしくて見てられない
- It looks dangerous and hard to keep watching a five-year-old use a knife.

In a similar way, used for a characteristics, it means someone who you cannot leave assuredly, in this case because of her oddity/unpredictability. To some extent, "precarious" is a closer word (though I don't know it can be used to describe a character).

Comment: You can certainly describe someone as having a precarious character.